# Get col names and index based on dataframe value

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe df_corr like this

```
  A2M.AX    ABC.AX    AGL.AX    AHY.AX    ALL.AX    AMC.AX    AMP.AX  
A2M.AX  1.000000 -0.505433  0.687367  0.223044 -0.664764 -0.199477   
ABC.AX -0.505433  1.000000 -0.801770 -0.606418  0.860923  0.332359   
AGL.AX  0.687367 -0.801770  1.000000  0.394378 -0.917379 -0.193461  
AHY.AX  0.223044 -0.606418  0.394378  1.000000 -0.483766 -0.063892  
ALL.AX -0.664764  0.860923 -0.917379 -0.483766  1.000000  0.177633
```

i want to get the index and column names based on value 
This is my attempt:

```
df_corr[(df_corr>0.7)&(df_corr<1)]


 A2M.AX    ABC.AX    AGL.AX    AHY.AX    ALL.AX  AMC.AX    AMP.AX  

ABC.AX       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.860923     NaN  
AGL.AX       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN     NaN        
AHY.AX       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN     NaN       
ALL.AX       NaN  0.860923       NaN       NaN       NaN     NaN
```

Expect result:

```
AGL.AX ALL.AX
AMC.AX ABC.AX
```

Comment: Is your output supposed to be an nx2 dataframe, a MultiIndex, a list-of-lists, or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `stack` to reshape/pivot the dataframe, and transform the index to a multiindex:

```
df_corr[(df_corr>0.7)&(df_corr<1)].stack()
Out[79]: 
A2M.AX        
ABC.AX  AMC.AX    0.860923
ALL.AX  AGL.AX    0.860923
dtype: float64

df_corr[(df_corr>0.7)&(df_corr<1)].stack().index.values
Out[80]: array([('ABC.AX', 'AMC.AX'), ('ALL.AX', 'AGL.AX')], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Please explain this better; [`stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) reshapes/pivots the dataframe, and transforms the index to a multiindex e.g. `('ABC.AX', 'AMC.AX')`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using NumPy indexing, which avoids having to subset your dataframe.

```
import numpy as np

condition = df.gt(0.7) & df.lt(1)

x, y = map(list, zip(*np.where(condition.values)))

res = list(zip(df.index[x], df.columns[y]))

[('ABC.AX', 'AMC.AX'), ('ALL.AX', 'AGL.AX')]
```